# Append behavior to "build" action on NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, ide

I’m working on a netbeans platform/maven application, that requires a custom .jar to be on its /platform/core folder when its run.
We use IzPack to create the installer, so it’s easy to copy the .jar to its destination when the app is installed.

However, on the development environment, **how can I copy the required .jar file to the /target/myApp/platform/core folder every time the “Build”, “Clean and build” of “Build with Dependencies” action is executed in NetBeans?**

I’ve completely no idea of where to start or what to do, so any pointers to reading material are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is few ways to do it, but I think the best way is adding new resource description in your pom.xml. Let your jar be placed at ‘project_folder/jar-resources’ folder then your pom.xml will look like:

```
<build>
...
<resources>
...
<resource>
<directory>src/main/resources</directory>
</resource>
<resource>
<directory>jar-resources</directory>
<targetPath>../myApp/platform/core</targetPath>
</resource>
</resources>
...
</build>
```

Remember that if you don’t use standard resource place ‘src/main/resource’ you can’t use first resource declaration.